# Repeat onClick funtkion after 5 seconds

Tags: android, loops, button, onclick, repeat

I created an `onClick` function, which creates a polyline and shows a `toast`. I want to repeat this function every 5 seconds after the button is clicked. How do I do this?

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view){

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Track erstellen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    for (int e=0 ; e < points.size();e++) {
        options = new PolylineOptions().width(7).color(Color.rgb(0, 139, 69)).geodesic(true);
        for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
            LatLng point = points.get(i);
            options.add(point);
        }
        line = mGoogleMap.addPolyline(options);
    }
}
```

Comment: Make use of Handler. keep your toast and other statement in another function. Call the function from the handler :)

Answer (score 2):

To call it repeatedly create a function for it

```
public void onClickMethod(){
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Track erstellen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    for (int e=0 ; e < points.size();e++) {
        options = new PolylineOptions().width(7).color(Color.rgb(0, 139, 69)).geodesic(true);
        for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
            LatLng point = points.get(i);
            options.add(point);
        }
        line = mGoogleMap.addPolyline(options);
    }
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            onClickMethod();
        }
    },5000);
}
```

where 5000 is your 5 seconds delay

and in onClick method just call onClickMethod();

Comment: It does not know the .postDelayed. Maybe because this code is in a fragment?

Comment: make sure to import android.os.Handler;

Comment: If I do it like this there are still errors. When I import the Handler there is an error called "Interface expected here".

And in the code Handler handler = new Handler(); is the error "Handler is abstract; cannot be instantiated"

If I don't write (View view) after the onClick, the code is not able to find my button.

Comment: You are importing the wrong Handler. just see at the top of your java file above class name there should be a import line for Handler remove that line and paste  `import android.os.Handler;`

Answer (score 0):

Timer will help you to call a function for every 5 seconds.

```
 public void timer() 
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            drawPloyLine();
                        } catch (Exception e) {

                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 5000);

    public void drawPloyLine(){

        for (int e=0 ; e < points.size();e++) {
            options = new PolylineOptions().width(7).color(Color.rgb(0,
                    139, 69)).geodesic(true);
            for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
                LatLng point = points.get(i);
                options.add(point);
            }
            line = mGoogleMap.addPolyline(options);
        }
    }
```